# Make a JRadioButton unclickable

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I wonder if it is possible to make a JRadioButton unclickable? I have implemented some functions in an application, but i would still like to show the name of the functions yet to be implemented. The user chooses from a JRadioGroup so i'd like to add all the functions as radiobuttons and then make some of them unclickable, but so far i have not been able to figure out how.

Regards
Jesper

Comment: setEnabled i believe should do the trick

Comment: mybutton.setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the JRadioButton disabled using following Code

Sample Code

```
    JRadioButton butt = new JRadioButton( "Button 1: " );
    butt.setEnabled( false );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using: [`setEnabled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)

This can enable / disable any component.